# How can i use recursion in c# to build models and assign values to the properties?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a dictionary in c# with Key , Value  pairs. How can I build models with the associated properties as the value ?

```
 If the dictionary has data as follows 
  Product,Stage               
  Product,DateCreated      
  Product,AccountId           
  Product,Name    
  Account,LastName           
  Account,Name
```

They keys are Product and Value(property) is Stage and so on.

```
I want to generate dynamically classes like 

public class Product
{
    public string Stage { get; set; }
    public string DateCreated{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
}
```

and the same for Account.

How can I traverse the dictionary starting from bottom up so create the Account first  and create these classes ? I will assign the values later.

Comment: Can you post some code that populates an example dictionary with example values? I am not sure what "Product,Stage" means or what the type parameters of your dictionary are.

Comment: Are you generating source code or serializing data?

Comment: Do you want to generate classes definition on-the-fly while running a program or do you want to generate some .cs files for another project ?

Comment: I have a dictionary and a list of objects that are populated. So from the example above the Product would be the class name and the Value is the property, so basically generating a model class for that dictionary.                                                                                                    I also have a list of objects that I need to create a model class for as well.   In my code I need to be able to instantiate these and assign values to the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use something like T4, which has built in support in visual studio.  This assumes you can read the dictionary from somewhere into memory.  I'll leave the reading the dictionary to you.

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Model
{<#Go();#>}

<#+
    void Go()
    {
        Dictionary<string /*modelName*/, string[] /*properties*/> modelDict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

        //... read the dictionary ...

        foreach(var model in modelDict)
        {
            WriteLine("   class " + model.Key + "\r\n" +
                      "   {\r\n");
            foreach(var prop in model.Value)
                WriteLine("      public string " + prop + " {get; set;}\r\n");
            WriteLine("   }\r\n\r\n");
        }
    }
#>
```

Save this to a *.tt file in your project and it should create a *.cs file.

Comment: My dictionary has duplicate keys. So I have had to use a list of objects. Is it the same for a list of objects ? Also the above will produce multiple classes of the same type , so 4 Product classes ?

Comment: It is essentially the same.  For example, your dictionary would have key 'Product', and the value is an array of properties, {'Stage', 'Name', etc.}.